# Open a file with specific page from an anchor tag

Tags: html, excel, pdf, anchor

I am trying to open a specific page in a file from an anchor tag(`<a href=""></a>`). The anchor tag is in a xls file. When I tried doing this I am able specify find the specified page but when I pass a parameter I am not able to find the location of the page. Can anyone help me in this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to click here: [Page 4 of a PDF outlining Ghostscript's new color management architecture](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/gs/doc/GS9_Color_Management.pdf#page=4) -- it should open a PDF on page 4. Works for me with Internet Explorer 7 as well as with Google Chrome v6.

The method to indicate the URL is http://some.web.server/path/to/file.pdf#page=33 ...

(I only *assume* you want to open PDFs in that way because you tagged the question with the PDF tag....)